# Hash Set and Array List performances

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, arraylist, hashset

I have implemented a method which simply loops around a set of CSV files that contain data on a number of different module. This then adds the 'moduleName' into a hashSet. (Code shown below)

I have used a hashSet as it guarantees no duplicates are inserted instead of an ArrayList which would have to use the contain() method and iterate through the list to check if it is already there.

I believe using the hash set has a better performance than an array list.
Am I correct in stating that?

Also, can somebody explain to me:

1. How to work the performance for each data structure if used?
2. What is the complexity using the big-O notation?

   ```
   HashSet<String> modulesUploaded = new HashSet<String>();

   for (File f: marksheetFiles){
       try {
           csvFileReader = new CSVFileReader(f);
           csvReader = csvFileReader.readFile();
           csvReader.readHeaders();

           while(csvReader.readRecord()){
               String moduleName = csvReader.get("Module");

               if (!moduleName.isEmpty()){
                   modulesUploaded.add(moduleName);
               }
           }

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       csvReader.close();
   }
   return modulesUploaded;
   ```

   }

Comment: You probably want to include the language you're using as one of the tags (you'll have to eliminate one of the others, but the language is almost undoubtedly more important).

Answer (score 53):

[My experiment](https://github.com/chaschev/experiments-with-microbes/blob/master/src/main/java/stackoverflow/q6462055/HashMapVsListMicrobe.java#L25) shows that `HashSet` is faster than an `ArrayList` starting at collections of 3 elements inclusively.

A complete results table

```
| Boost  |  Collection Size  |
|  2x    |       3 elements  |
|  3x    |      10 elements  |
|  6x    |      50 elements  |
|  12x   |     200 elements  |  <= proportion 532-12 vs 10.000-200 elements
|  532x  |  10.000 elements  |  <= shows linear lookup growth for the ArrayList
```

Answer (score 26):

They're completely different classes, so the question is: what kind of behaviour do you want?

`HashSet` ensures there are no duplicates, gives you an O(1) `contains()` method but doesn't preserve order.
`ArrayList` doesn't ensure there are no duplicates, `contains()` is O(n) but you can control the order of the entries.

Answer (score 22):

> I believe using the hash set has a better performance than an array list. Am I correct in stating that?

With many (whatever it means) entries, yes. With small data sizes, raw linear search could be faster than hashing, though. Where exactly the break-even is, you have to just measure. My gut feeling is that with fewer than 10 elements, linear look-up is probably faster; with more than 100 elements hashing is probably faster, but that's just my feeling...

Lookup from a HashSet is constant time, O(1), provided that the hashCode implementation of the elements is sane. Linear look-up from a list is linear time, O(n).

Answer (score 5):

It depends upon the usage of the data structure.

You are storing the data in `HashSet`, and for your case for storage `HashSet` is better than `ArrayList` (as you do not want duplicate entries). But just storing is not the usual intent.

It depends as how you wish to read and process the stored data. If you want sequential access or random index based access then `ArrayList` is better or if ordering does not matter then `HashSet` is better.

If ordering matters but you want to do lot of modifications (additions and deletions) the  LinkedList is better.

For accessing a particular element `HashSet` will have time complexity as O (1) and if you would have used `ArrayList` it would have been O (N) as you yourself have pointed out you would have to `iterate` through the list and see if the element is not present.