# HashSet vs ArrayList Speed? Insert vs Lookup ( Java )

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196343/hash-set-and-array-list-performances) it made me curious as to which to use, Hashset vs ArrayList. The Hashset seems to have a better lookup and ArrayList has a better insert (for many many objects). So I my question is, since I can't insert using an ArrayList, then search through it using a HashSet, I'm going to have to pick one or the other. Would inserting with an ArrayList, converting to a HashSet to do the lookups, be SLOWER overall than to just insert into a HashSet then lookup? Or just stick with the ArrayList, although the lookup is worse, the inserting makes up for it?

Comment: "Would inserting with an ArrayList, converting to a HashSet to do the lookups, be SLOWER overall than to just insert into a HashSet then lookup?" Yes.

Comment: Yeah I figured this was the case, any overall suggestion? ArrayList or Hashset?

Comment: @jp093121. Apples or oranges? Puppies or cars?

Comment: Depends on your data.

Comment: HashSet is NOT a replacement for ArrayList in general. See JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html vs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html.

Comment: It depends entirely on what you have to do.  The two are not equivalent, so in cases where you could use either one, determine what's important and what's not.  If you don't need/want duplicates and just want to know whether an object exists in the collection, a HashSet is more appropriate.  If order matters, or if you're iterating a lot, ArrayList.  If you don't care either way, then time it.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" -- Donald Knuth. Assuming you realize this, the next question is what are you using now, and what kind of performance issue are you seeing? When writing new code, whether to use a `Set` or a `List` should be based on what you are trying to do (per @isnot2bad and @cHao).

Comment: Wow thanks for all of the answers so fast, good to know.

Comment: Why don`t you try treeset instead. they are much faster and keep your data sorted. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 2):

It very much depends on the size of the collection and the way you use it. I.e. you can reuse the same `HashSet` for copying and this would save you time. Or you can keep them up-to-date.

Creating a `HashSet` copy for each element lookup will always be slower.

You can also utilize `LinkedHashSet` which has quick insertion and a `HashSet`'s look up speed at cost of a little  worse memory consumption and `O(N)` `index(int)` operation.

Answer (score 1):

You must decide for your specific application which tradeoff pays off better. Do you first insert everything, then spend the rest of the time looking up, maybe occasionally adding a few more? Use `HashSet`. Do you have a lot of duplicates, which you must suppress? Another strong point for `HashSet`. Do you insert a lot all the time and only do an occasional lookup? Then use `ArrayList`. And so on, there are many more combinations and in some cases you'll have to benchmark it to see.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally depends on your use case. If you implement the `hashCode` method correctly, the insert operation of `HashSet` is also an `O(1)` operation. If you don't need randomly access the elements(using index), and you don't want duplicates, `HashSet` would be a better choice.