# How to construct complex "if" statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am working on an android app which compares many random variables.

Column "A", for example has 4 variables, column "B" has 4 variables... etc. There are 5 columns total. The variables are random from a set of 5 numbers.

Right now I have about 100 if statements which are like:

```
If (a1==b1)
{If (b1==c1)
```

I list all possible outcomes... a1.equals b2 etc etc... I began rewriting it to use || but I am still coming out with thousands of lines of code and I often get errors. I've searched the web but I keep coming up with no results.

I guess what I am looking for is something like...

```
If ((a1||a2||a3||a4)==(b1||b2||b3||b4))
{    
     //check if ==(c1||c2||c3||c4) etc...
}
Else
{
     Do something...
}
```

I just consistently am getting compile errors and crashes whenever I write stuff like this. Also I cannot figure out how to check stuff like  (a1&&a2)==(b1||b2) etc etc...

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated Thanks!

Edit: For anyone who has a similar issue, I have found "while and for loops" to be extremely helpful. Here is a site that has helped clarify it for me, I hope it helps you as well... http://www.javaranch.com/drive/loop.html

Comment: Step 1: Use `if`, not `If`.

Comment: It's unclear from your examples what you're actually asking. Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: I normally use if... It auto capitalized If for some reason... :P

Comment: @oliver, you need to understand logical operators and bitwise operators. Logical operators can simplify your solution. Next time, don't generalise the question. Be specific and post your code. People are out here to tell you a solution provided all the inputs

Comment: If your if statements are really that complex, perhaps you have a more fundamental design problem that you should address rather than trying to simplify the syntax.

Comment: It sounds as though you just need a nested `for` loop which looks for equal values in a 2D array.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe it's better to use completely different approach.

Comment: A lot of people are downvoting this question, but I disagree. It's actually a good question for people to see. This is the type of question that others can learn from. The answer is, "don't."

Comment: What the heck is `(a1&&a2)==(b1||b2)` supposed to mean? in English please. This question deserves a downvote until it is made clearer.

Comment: @Patrick I think the problem is that knowing how to write the question more clearly would require knowledge of the solution to the problem. Although I'm all for plain english additions.

Comment: @Patrick && as well as || are operators in a language called Java... so in this context, English wouldn't entirely be appropriate ;)

Comment: @Oliver You stated that the variables are "numbers." Those operators are logical-and and logical-or. So your pseudocode is not semantically correct Java. In fact it won't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now I have about 100 if statements

Stop right there.

This is almost **never** okay, and in the extremely rare cases where it *might* be okay, you will *know* that this is the case.

The reason this question is getting downvotes (which I disagree with, this question deserves to be asked) is that too many programmers have had their eyes bleed after having to look at code written with 100's of complex if statements. It's practically a PTSD thing. It physically *hurts* us.

If you are needed to write that many if conditions, it sounds like a serious design flaw. In this case, there definitely is, and it's a pretty simple one that can be solved with basic data structures and algorithms knowledge.

Whenever you have a large number of related data items and you want to perform repetitive actions on them, you typically need some kind of collection, and a some kind of algorithm to do work on the collection.

It sounds likes you need an `Array` or an `ArrayList` of some other type of `List` to store all of your values. Then, you can write an algorithm that accesses the variables within the list with some kind of loop and perform whatever logic you need on them.

Other answers will likely provide code that will be useful, but this will not solve the underlying issue. It is better for you to come up with a solution yourself. You can do it, and will be far better for you to do so! You need to think more generally about your problem, and then (and only then) narrow down on specific solution methods. Solve the problem on paper before you write any code. Be very clear what exactly you need to do (without thinking about how you would implement it) and then once you have a good solution, try to translate it into code. *Writing the code once you have a solution to the problem should be the easy part!*

I recommend reading up on data structures and algorithms, as it sounds like you aren't very familiar with them; they are a critical skill to have in your toolbelt. You don't need to be an expert, but you will find you will have a much easier time programming the more you know about them.

You aren't stupid, you just are inexperienced. We all start learning somewhere, so don't be too discouraged by the responses of others.

Comment: I think an array list may help, thats where I may start. Most of my "if" are {if (a1==1) {a1 set background to... drawable} and since, like Nick said below, you can not say a1||a2||b1 ect. I've had to make a lot of programmatic background changes. 100, to be exact because I have 5 columns with 4 objects in each × 5 variables. So I am limited unless theres a way to check all and if (anything==variable1) {set background to...} it started out simple and over the last three months has turned to a behemoth, and thats why I am here... lol

Comment: Read up on for loops. Whenever you need to repeat behavior, you need a loop. Also, welcome to Stack Exchange. If you feel that any of the answers fully answers your question, remember to click the check mark and accept it.

Comment: After a breif look at a few sites that I like to use for coding, it seems that for loops probably will cut my code down to a third of the lines I have. Winner winner chicken dinner. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at both your examples you're limited to individual checks as follows

Either

```
if (a1==b1 || a1==c1 || b1== c1) {
   //stuff
```

Or

```
//as with the complex example above, using else-if will stop 
//subsequent checks running if a case has already been matched
if (a1==b1) {
   //stuff
} else if (b1==c1) { 
   //stuff
```

Java does not support grouped checks like

```
if ((a1||a2||a3||a4)==(b1||b2||b3||b4))
```

As a side note: I agree with the comment added by azurefrog while writing this - perhaps you have a design flaw which, if addressed, can reduce the complexity of this block.

If there is some reason you cannot simplify your code, perhaps you can limit yourself to a simple loop (depending on what logic you actually need, your question isn't explicit), something like the following:

```
List<Integer> leftSide = new ArrayList<>(); //i don't know your data type
leftSide.add(a1);
leftSide.add(a2);
...
List<Integer> rightSide = new ArrayList<>();
rightSide.add(b1);
rightSide.add(b2);
...

for (Integer leftItem : leftSide) {
    if (rightSide.contains(leftItem)) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a HashSet for speed purpose. A HashSet is like a List. A Collection. But it can only contains unique Keys. We create a HashSet and store the (condition:left) values to the set. Then we create another Collection and fill it with the (condition:right) data. After this we call a method which loops through the List and compare if the current Data from the List is in the HashSet. If it matches, it returns true to make sure that it doesnt need to continue (and loop through all matches). The Lambda makes your code just a little bit shorter and better to read.

```
Set<MyData> data = new HashSet<MyData>();
data.put(a1); 
data.put(a2);
data.put(a3);
data.put(a4);

List<MyData> dataSecond = new ArrayList<MyData>();
datasecond.add(...);

containsData(datasceond, data);

boolean containsData(ArrayList<MyData> datas, Set<MyData> hashSet) {
    // the for loops through the "Collection" containing the first datas and validate if those are in the second Collection HashSet. 
    for(MyData data : datas) if hashSet.contains(data) return true;
    return false;
}
```

or as Lambda (not tested)

```
boolean containsDataAsLambda(List<MyData> list, Set<MyData> set) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(t -> set.contains(t)); 
}
```

Why should you use HashSet instead of a List? Because a HashSet is faster, doesnt have an index and allow only unique entries.

[Hash Set and Array List performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196343/hash-set-and-array-list-performances)

Comment: If OP doesn't know that he can use a for loop and an array here, you expect him to understand the implementation of a `HashSet`? Or Lambdas?

Comment: Yes. Since he can use it as basic to learn the difference between a Set and a List. He asked for a Solution and this seems to be one.

Comment: Ironically I've read about HashSets, and heard about arrays, I just have never used them personally. I haven't built anything this camplex before.

Comment: Just modified and should be easier now.

Comment: `HashSet` would be potentially useful here, but, array or list is probably the better choice.

Comment: Also, I've been programming in Java for 5 years now and I still get confused by lambdas sometimes, so don't feel so bad about that.

Comment: Yeah. Lambdas are sometimes hard to understand. But Retrofit+RxJava+Lambdas is a pain. Just updated and wrote why he should use a Set.

Comment: I think your answer is much better now that you have edited it, but I'm still partial to saying a Set is overkill here.

Comment: "many random variables". Its for speed which is very important if you have tons of data. But yes, it could be solved with a List aswell.