# Stream and filter one list based on other list

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a list of objects. Those objects have a string variable. I also have a list of strings.

So something like this.

```
List<A> listA;

class A {

String x;

}
List<String> listB;
```

What I want to be able to do is stream and filter listA, based on whether x contains any of the string objects in List B.

Is this doable ?

Comment: Contains or equals?

Comment: You should show us how you would do this using regular loops so we have a more clear idea of what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<A> filtered = 
    listA.stream()
         .filter(a -> listB.stream().anyMatch(b -> x.a.contains(b)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I had to replace anyMatch with allMatch and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sure - just call `contains` in the `filter` clause:

```
List<A> filtered = 
    listA.stream().filter(a -> listB.contains(a.x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a `HashSet` to store the `String` values. The reason is a `HashSet` guarantees `O(1)` or constant time lookup. With a list, it is `O(n)`, meaning that a lookup (`.contains`) needs to iterate over all its elements in the worst case scenario.

So the following approach will be more efficient:

```
List<A> listA ...
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<>(); // populate setB
List<A> filteredA =
    listA.stream()
        .filter(a -> setB.contains(a.x)).collect(toList());
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19841066) answer for some concrete evidence of the performance difference.