# Better way to compare d in the if statment. What if i need to compare it to say 100 values?

Tags: java, if-statement

Better way to compare d in the if statement. What if i need to compare it to say 100 values?

```
int d = 0;
if(d == 3 || d == 8 || d == 1) {
   System.out.println("d is one of the special numbers!");
}
```

Comment: How big can `d` get?  You could use a `boolean[]` or a `BitSet` in some scenarios.

Comment: Be cautious when [copying content from other posts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/280642).  Normally the content license used here and the Terms of Service require that you provide attribution.  By the way, that other post already answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a list to contain the numbers, and then use that list for filtering in the `if` statement:

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
nums.add(1);
nums.add(3);
nums.add(8);

if (nums.contains(d)) {
    System.out.println("d is one of the special numbers!");
}
```

This might not perform as well as having the numbers directly in the `if` statement.  But, from a code readability/maintenance point of view, it is a better option IMO.

Or, we could use a `HashSet`, which might benefit from constant lookup time:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Then, after populating with the numbers, we would call `set.contains(d)` to check for the number.

Comment: Why not `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Oops... `HashSet` is a set which however is backed by a hash map (still constant lookup time).  Yeah...I've been spending too much time on the SQL tags.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196343/hash-set-and-array-list-performances what do you think the answer is ?

Comment: Set is the interface type, hashset is a specific implementation class. You should be using the set type on the left side of the assignment!

Comment: @TheScientificMethod When I initially answered with list, I wasn't thinking about performance, because for a small collection of numbers, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Because your elements will be unique, storing them in hashset is better.

Have a look at: [Hash Set and Array List performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196343/hash-set-and-array-list-performances)

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
mySet.add(2);
mySet.add(3);
mySet.add(4);
....

if(mySet.contains(d)) {
   System.out.println(d + " is one of the special numbers!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of special numbers and then iterate over them comparing against each value in the list:

```
List<Integer> specialNumbers = Arrays.asList('1', '3', '8');
        int d = '7';
        for (Integer specialNumber : specialNumbers) {
            if (userInput == specialNumber) {
                System.out.println("You've entered one of the special numbers!")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note that this might not do what you intend if `userInput` is a boxed primitive. Using `contains` would be preferable (or print the message `Collections.frequency` times, if it is really relevant to know howany occurrences there are).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an array or list, use a switch:

```
switch (d) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 8:  System.out.println("d is one of the special numbers");
             break;
    default: break; // Fall through in case d isn't a special number
}
```

`break` is an important keyword here, case basically goes through each value and checks if d is equal, and then executes  any statements it finds after matching 'd' until it reaches a `break` statement. For example,if I'd put:

```
switch (d) {
    case 1: System.out.println("d equals 1");
    case 3: System.out.println("d equals 3");
            break;
    /* More examples*/
}
```

and had tested it when d = 1 it would print "d equals 1" **and** "d equals 3."

Don't rely on switches for large sets of data, use a for loop instead.

Comment: "break is an important keyword here" indeed. Don't hide it on the end of the line. Put it on its own line (can't see it in Android app because it is off the right of the screen).

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer a = 5;
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Stream.of(a).anyMatch(ints::contains); // this will return boolean
```

If you want to pass not only one value, but list of values, and you don't want to change your code, you can use, code below.

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).allMatch(ints::contains); // true;
Stream.of(1,2,7).allMatch(ints::contains); // false;
```

Also, please be aware of NPE, if you pass to Stream.of() null, there will be NullPointerException.

But isn't problem if you use

```
Optional.of(ints).orElse(new ArrayList<>()).stream().allMatch(ints::contains)
```

I would prefer to use apache-common collections utils for my code, there is `Collections.emptyIfNull().stream() ...`
good method.

Comment: `ints.contains(a)` is a much easier way to write the third line.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if you want to change this for the future, you should change `contains` to `containsAll`, everywhere. I'm supposed to change anyMatch for allMath it also will work for one number, and two and so on. But if one of them doesn't belong to ints, will be false.